# Insert Sharepoint 2010 property in Visio diagram?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, visio

Is there any way to insert the Sharepoint Document ID property into a Visio diagram?

We use it for unique identification of documents and would like it to be printed on all diagrams.

Best regards,

Gustav

Answer (score 0):

You could create a ShapeSheet-Cell in the User-defined Cells Section, where you put any information.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting one of the Document Properties (such as Description or Tags).

### THE MANUAL STEPS

In Visio 2010 this would be **File > Options > Properties**
[image]

Create draw a simple rectangle and  then insert a field by using **Insert > Field** and selecting the name of the Document Property. These are all found in the **Document Info** category. Curiously "Tags" in the Document properties is called "Keywords" in the **Field** dialog.

[image]